# Trying to get a Symfony version number in my Bash script using a regular expression

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, symfony

When I call `bin/console --version` in a Symfony project from my terminal, I get `Symfony 4.4.3 (env: dev, debug: true)`
I like to do a match to see that verifies that the result of the command does in fact match the expected pattern.

I've got this pattern: https://regex101.com/r/n2hBR8/1

I've tried several things in my Bash script, but I can't get it to work:

```
#symfonyVersionRegex="Symfony\s\d{1}.*"
#symfonyVersionRegex="^Symfony\s\d{1}.*$"
symfonyVersionRegex="^Symfony\s\d.*$"

symfonyVersionRaw=`bin/console --version`

if [[ symfonyVersionRaw =~ $symfonyVersionRegex ]]; then
    echo Version number found
else
    echo Version number NOT found
fi
```

When I echo the symfonyVersionRaw I get the expected version string, so that works but no matter what I try, I always get a negative result ("Version number NOT found").

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have an error where you do not put `$` in front of `symfonyVersionRaw`.

Then you should match digits with `[0-9]` or with `[[:digit:]]`.

Take a look here: [How to match digits in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968020/how-to-match-digits-in-regex).